# How to calculate or see the performance of my database in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-design

I want to check the performance of my database in mysql. I googled and came to know about show full processlist etc commands, but not very clear. i just want to know and calaculate the performance of database in terms of how much heap memory it is taking and other such.

Is there any way to know and assess the performance of the database. so that I can optimize and improve the performance.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026488/mysql-query-monitor-tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic tool is [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) which will work with any recent version of MySQL. It's not as powerful as the enterprise version, but is a great place to start.

The configuration can be exposed with `SHOW VARIABLES` and the current state of the system is exposed through `SHOW STATUS`. These status numbers are what ends up being graphed in most tools.

Don't forget that you can do a lot of monitoring on the application side, turning on database logs for instance. Barring that you can enable the "slow query" log in MySQL to check which queries are having the most impact. These can then be diagnosed with `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: Thanks I actually looking for such answers..!can you please guide me how to enable those logs.. I actually tried to enable them but giving some errors like
**
121212 10:59:15 [Warning] Ignoring user change to 'root' because the user was set to 'mysql' earlier on the command line

121212 10:59:15 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/xxx-desktop.lower-test
121212 10:59:15 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/xxx-desktop.lower-test**

Comment: If you have a specific question about how to enable the slow query logs, it might be worth posting that separately. If it doesn't work it could be any number of things that are interfering, the most obvious of which being file permissions for the `mysql` user.

Answer (score 0):

Download [mysql enterprise tools](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/monitor.html). They will allow you to monitor load on the server as well as performance of individual queries.

Comment: Thank you Murtuza...for your early and valuable answer..!

Comment: Isn't this only available for the commercial version of MySQL?

Comment: @Murtuza: Is n't free? I think it is enterprise version. It is asking me for registration and buy it. Is there any other way then?

Comment: There is also a free version - mysql gui tools(now known as workbench). They are free but does not contain enterprise fetters. Download it from here - http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Answer (score 0):

You can use open source tools from Percona called as Percona Toolkit and start using some useful tools which can help you in Efficiently archive rows, Find duplicate indexes, Summarize MySQL servers, Analyze queries from logs and tcpdump and Collect vital system information when problems occur.

You can try experimenting with `Performance_Schema` tables avialable in MySQL v5.6 onwards which can give a detailed information of query, database statistics.
http://www.markleith.co.uk/2012/07/04/mysql-performance-schema-statement-digests/