# Server Monitoring tools Apache/MySQL

Tags: mysql, apache

my boss has asked me to find a tool that will monitor our sever health.  Some kind of desktop application preferably that we can keep an eye on and will monitor us when capacity goes over a certain level, or we approach max storage etc.

We need to monitor both MySQL and Apache. I'm guessing I might need two tools.

THanks in advance

Comment: There are already some MySQL monitoring tools listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026488/mysql-query-monitor-tool

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/)? it's not desktop... but i don't know why do you want to have a desktop solution?

Comment: It was just what he suggested but not a necessity. We use Windows computer in our office if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

you can monitor apache with SNMP module like mod_apache_snmp and tools like OpenNMS, and Nagios. Nagios supports monitoring mysql also.

Answer (score 0):

You might also like to look at Megamon (http://www.megamon.com). Megamon is a complete monitoring solution capable of graphing numerous system performance aspects as well as escalating alerts and much more.
Megamon is not a desktop solution but runs as a Virtual Appliance. However, since it has a web interface, it is just as easy to use as a desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SeaLion](https://sealion.com). SeaLion is a cloud based Linux server monitoring tool. Getting started is as easy as executing a command. It installs an agent at /usr/local/sealion-agent and runs as an unprivileged user (sealion). This agent will collect data at regular intervals across servers and this data will be available on your workspace. The latest version is shipped with NGINX, Apache, MySQL, MongoDB and Redis monitoring capability. It is free for 1 server with a 12 hours data retention policy.